# iOS : Strange NSSortDescriptor behavior

Tags: ios, nssortdescriptor

What is the difference between:

```
NSSortDescriptor * nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

and

```
NSSortDescriptor * nameSortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES comparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [obj1 localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:obj2];
}];
```

?

I'm using NSFetchedResultsController.
In the second case, I've got a `"The fetched object at index 241 has an out of order section name 'Z. Objects must be sorted by section name'"`error.

In the first case, no problem. But i have to use the NSCompare in the second case...

Comment: What do your objects look like?

Comment: Their name property is a NSString, if it's the question... obj1 and obj2 are strings